# Assembly x86, print new line after each word in a string

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

Need to print separate token in a string in different line, but can't figure out to print out a new line.

From the tutorial I have, it says "nwln" in the examples, but it doesn't work in my code.

The code I have now only prints all the words in one line no spaces.

```
lab2:
    cmp [ecx],byte ' ' 
    je lab1
    cmp [ecx], byte 0
    je lab3
    inc edx
    inc ecx
    jmp lab2
lab1:   
    sub ecx,edx
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    int 80h

    add ecx, edx
    inc ecx 
    mov edx,0
    jmp lab2
```

ok I think I have solved it by using another variable newline in .data and another register to print a new line

Comment: To print a newline character you should only have to print the character `0x0a` if you are on Linux.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks! but I still don't get how to print the char 0xa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to be using *NASM* on Linux. `nwln` is a macro that is part of an [Assembler Tutorial](http://www.scs.carleton.ca/sivarama/org_book/org_book_web/source_code.html) based on the code from the book *Guide to Assembly Language Programming in Linux*. The library is made up of a macro called `nwln` that prints the LineFeed(LF) character `0x0a` to standard output. You can download the files `io.mac` and `io.o` from the link above. They are contained inside the [ZIP file](http://www.scs.carleton.ca/sivarama/org_book/org_book_web/linux_nasm_progs.zip) for *NASM/Linux*. You copy `io.mac` and `io.o` to your project directory. You have to include the macro file at the top of your program. Your code would look something like:

```
%include "io.mac"

SYS_EXIT  equ 1
SYS_READ  equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4
STDIN     equ 0
STDOUT    equ 1

section .text
    global main
main:
    mov ecx,msg3
    mov edx,0       ; Set the length
    jmp lab2

lab2:
    cmp [ecx],byte ' '
    je lab1
    cmp [ecx], byte 0
    je lab3
    inc edx
    inc ecx
    jmp lab2
lab1:
    sub ecx,edx
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    int 80h
    nwln
    add ecx, edx
    inc ecx
    mov edx,0
    jmp lab2

lab3:
    sub ecx,edx
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    int 80h
    nwln

    mov eax, SYS_EXIT
    int 80h

segment .data
     msg3 db 'this string', 0x0
```

To compile and link in a 32-bit environment you'd use something like:

```
nasm -f elf32 project.asm
ld -emain -melf_i386 -o project project.o io.o
```

You need to add `io.o` as a linker object to resolve the functions that are needed by the macros.

If you don't wish to rely on `io.o` the code below contains the equivalent macro and function that will implement `nwln` a similar way:

```
%macro  nwln  0
        call    proc_nwln
%endmacro

SYS_EXIT  equ 1
SYS_READ  equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4
STDIN     equ 0
STDOUT    equ 1

section .text
    global main
main:
    mov ecx,msg3
    mov edx,0       ; Set the length
    jmp lab2

lab2:
    cmp [ecx],byte ' '
    je lab1
    cmp [ecx], byte 0
    je lab3
    inc edx
    inc ecx
    jmp lab2
lab1:
    sub ecx,edx
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    int 80h
    nwln
    add ecx, edx
    inc ecx
    mov edx,0
    jmp lab2

lab3:
    sub ecx,edx
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    int 80h
    nwln

    mov eax, SYS_EXIT
    int 80h

proc_nwln:
    pusha
    mov    eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov    ebx, STDOUT
    mov    ecx, new_line
    mov    edx, 0x1
    int    0x80
    popa
    ret

segment .data
     msg3 db 'this string', 0x0
     new_line db 0x0a
```

You can then compile with something like:

```
nasm -f elf32 project.asm
ld -emain -melf_i386 -o project project.o
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i see how it works with nwln now.

Comment: Is there any other way to print a new line without using nwln?

Comment: To print a newline is pretty the same process as printing a string to standard out. So not really. You can add `0xa` to the end of any string as well. For instance `helloworld db 'hello world', 0xa, 0`if displayed would print `hello world` followed be a newline.